# Alter Image on mouseover and mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have two arrays with the list of images name like this

```
array 1 = ["arrow1.png", "arrow2.png", "arrow3.png", "arrow4.png", "arrow5.png"]

array 2 = ["arrow_over1.png", "arrow_over2.png", "arrow_over3.png", "arrow_over4.png", "arrow_over5.png"]
```

I want to change the image in div tag with `id="alter_img"` on `mouseover` and `mouseleave`
On `mouseover` it should be `"arrow1.png"` and on `mouseleave` it should be `arrow_over1.png`

Structure is like this

```
<div id="alter_img">
  <img src="arrow1.png">
  <img src="arrow2.png">
  <img src="arrow3.png">
  <img src="arrow4.png">
  <img src="arrow5.png">
</div>
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Use `data` attributes:

#### HTML

```
<div id="alter_img">
    <img src="arrow1.png" data-hover_src="arrow_over1.png">
    <img src="arrow2.png" data-hover_src="arrow_over2.png">
    <img src="arrow3.png" data-hover_src="arrow_over3.png">
    <img src="arrow4.png" data-hover_src="arrow_over4.png">
    <img src="arrow5.png" data-hover_src="arrow_over5.png">
</div>
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#alter_img > img").hover(function() {
        $(this).data("orig_src", $(this).attr("src"));
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).data("hover_src"));
    }, function(){
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).data("orig_src"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing, as you mention the arrays that you actually want to change the src property of each image on mouseenter and mouseout. If this is the case then try

```
$("#alter_img > img").hover( function( ) {
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    $(this).attr( "src", Array1[ Array2.indexOf(src) ] );
},
function( ) {
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    $(this).attr( "src", Array2[ Array1.indexOf(src) ] );
});
```

Demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/8qy7k/5/)

Answer (score 1):

I Have got the best answer

```
$('img').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
$(this).attr({
    src: $(this).attr('data-other-src') 
    , 'data-other-src': $(this).attr('src') 
})
});
```

and image tag would be

```
<img data-other-src="arrow_over1.png" src="arrow1.png">
```

Comment: also this is not the question you asked...

and in any case my CSS answer is best!

Comment: James i think u haven't tried my answer, It's working well and it's much more optimized. I am not comparing it with your answer. Your logic is also good one

Comment: I was only joking. Though with my CSS example you would not need to preload your images :)

Comment: @devnull69 You are absolutely allowed to get reputation for answering your own question.  As a matter of fact, [it's explicitly encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/).

Comment: Thanks casperOne, I think no one have concentrated on answer of mine. If anyone have, then negative votes would not be there.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better using CSS.

Merge each of your original and overstate button into one image with each state next to the other.

Then you can simply use css to move the visible area of the button from "normal" to "over" with no JavaScript:

```
// button normally. Because we specify a width and height that is all that
// will be shown of our background. e.g. Our "normal state"
a.myButton {
    display:block;
     width:200px;
    height:80px;
    padding:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:url(images/my-button-sprite.png) no-repeat top left;
 }

// This will switch the button to our right side (or our "over state")
a:hover.myButton  {
    background:url(images/my-button-sprite.png) no-repeat top right;
}
```

Or if you really want to do it your way:

```
$('#alter_img > img').mouseover(function(){
    var idIndex = array1.indexOf($(this).attr('src'));
    if(idIndex != -1)
        $(this).attr('src', array2[idIndex]);

}).mouseleave(function(){

    var idIndex = array2.indexOf($(this).attr('src'));
    if(idIndex != -1)
        $(this).attr('src', array1[idIndex]);
});
```

Comment: #alter_img is a DIV and not an IMG

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
   onmouseover=document.getElementById("alter_img").src="arrow1.png"          
   onmouseout=document.getElementById("alter_img").src="arrow_over1.png"
```